# Get list of record from one to many table sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, one-to-many

I have two table which have one to many relationship

Example :

```
Table Buy : BuyID, BuyName
Table BuyItems: BuyItemID, Buy_BuyID, Quantity, Amount
```

Now I want to create trigger so whenever user insert to table buy, I can insert to table :

Buy_Summary :

TotalQuantity (which is sum from all quantity in table BuyItems which from record Buy.BuyID=BuyItems.Buy_BuyID)

TotalAmount (which is sum from all amount in table BuyItems which from record Buy.BuyID=BuyItems.Buy_BuyID)

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you write the select statement from the two existing tables? I would suggest not doing this in the first place. You are storing calculated values which is fraught with peril. What happens when the BuyItems are modified because the order needs to change? You are going to have to write a LOT of logic to keep this in synch. It would be far better to just calculate it when you need it.

Comment: @Sean Lange is right. This is a scenario for a view, not a trigger. Using a view will also improve insert/update performance on your Buy and BuyItems tables.

Remember, every piece of data in your database should have one and only one canonical location. 

Also, I would suggest renaming your tables. Buy is not a noun in English, and table names are traditionally nouns.

Comment: I am already trying using inner join but I can't get the total quantity and amount. and from record it suppose just for history so buyItems can't be change

Comment: How can you not get the total quantity? It is a very basic query with a simple aggregate.

Comment: I don't know how to get list of BuyItems. I am new in SQL Server. I can do it with linq but I have no idea how to do it with sql server

Comment: Well doing this in a trigger is a horrible plan. You will be fighting that forever. Put this in a view instead. Then go look up the SUM aggregate function. It is is what you want to use here.